# How to place centered border bottom with fixed width after h2?

Tags: html, css

How to place centered `border-bottom` with fixed width (100px) after `h2` (which can be longer or shorter depending on text)?

**CODE**

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<h2>Something</h2>
```

I am trying to do following

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74n5nkoo/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have a fixed width border bottom, you can add this to `h2:after {`:

`margin-left: -50px;`

Imagine `left: 50%;` shifting the left edge point to the center. This means that your border-bottom's left-most end would be at the center point. This is why you need to do `margin-left: -50px;`.

Here are some useful links on centering things in CSS:

1. [w3c](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)
2. [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

**Working example:**

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<h2>Something</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `transform: translateX(-50%)` in your pseudo element `::after`, so no matter the text, it will always be centered

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center
}
h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid magenta;
}
h2:last-of-type {
  top: 100px
}
```

```html
<h2>
Something
</h2>
<h2>
Something  More here
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

use negative margin left by dividing width into 2  like 100/2= 50;

```css
h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<h2>
Something
</h2>
```